# Syntax error - PHP if statement in html td tag

Tags: php, html

I get this message in my browser: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

I have been making a HTML table showing prices on a Woocommerce product.

I have seen a lot of similar issues, but cannot relate to my own problem.

The problem should be in this code...

```
            <tr>
                <td>'. $product_variation->get_name() .'</td>
                <td>'. $product_variation->get_regular_price() .'</td>
                <td>'
                 if($sale_price) {
                   echo $sale_price;
                    }else {
                   echo $product_variation->get_regular_price();
                    }
                '</td>
            </tr>';´´´
```

Comment: I'm sure you already figure it out. The answer is in the error message: "syntax error". This is how you embed PHP code in HTML: `<td><?php if (...) {...} ?></td>`

Comment: I've done this a lot of times before, and also know the method you mention. The problem is just that the code construction is different and therefore gets the error.

Answer (score 0):

use php Tags around this:-

```
<?php
if($sale_price) {
  echo $sale_price;
}else {
echo $product_variation->get_regular_price();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Mohit
I've tried to do as you wrote, but it doesn't work...
https://snag.gy/LWtjmp.jpg